# Looking for departure and arrival time of a flight from 2013

Tags: delays

Hope somebody can help me in finding the departure and arrival time of flight DE 5314 from Frankfurt to Mauritius on 16.08.2013.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot: Find online flight schedules on the airlines website, if they have them.  Not by search, but like a document that lists times.  Then go to archive.org and look for a copy of their website close to that date and try to find the same thing.

Or go to http://flightaware.com/live/flight/CFG5314 and there is a link to purchase the history.  Unfortunately, the history for this flight is not automated but the contact link hints that they might be able to do something.  If there's a legal issue, Condor might be forced to reveal it.  If not, they might respond to sweet talk and/or money.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the exact day but it's very likely there was a schedule and then https://www.amazon.de/Take-off-Condor-Boeing-Frankfurt-Mauritius-Cockpit-Fl%C3%BCge/dp/B00HW1QG6M surely this mentions when they took off or landed.

Comment: How can a video of the cockpit possibly answer a specific arrival and departure time?

Comment: If they would mention or show the time...? Why not?